# Allowing ajax link clicks to propagate

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript

A click event on a link with the `use-ajax` class on it does not seem to propagate up the DOM. Is this true? If so, is there a setting that will allow it to propagate?

Not being a JS whizz, I'm struggling to see where the call is made (`preventDefault`? `return false`?) that blocks the propagation. I've had a look at misc/ajax.js and there is a setting `element_settings.prevent` that looks like it might be relevant, but I haven't found any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in `Drupal.ajax.prototype.eventResponse`, round about line 265:

```
// For radio/checkbox, allow the default event. On IE, this means letting
// it actually check the box.
if (typeof element.type != 'undefined' && (element.type == 'checkbox' || element.type == 'radio')) {
  return true;
}
else {
  return false;
}
```

It's hard-coded, but this is JS - you can just monkey-patch `Drupal.ajax.prototype.eventResponse` and get it to do whatever you like :)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Do you happen to know why "return false" is used instead of "preventDefault"? Seems to me that preventDefault would do what is intended and no more

Comment: Returning `false` is equivalent to running `event.preventDefault()` _and_ `event.stopPropagation()`. If I had to guess, I'd say that's why they've done it - just for brevity

Comment: Sorry, you're asking why the use of `stopPropagation()` at all, aren't you...'fraid I don't know that one. Might be an oversight, might be intentional